# Launch application through Powershell in elevated mode

Tags: powershell

I have an RDS environment with an epos application that runs fine under the user that initially installed it but requires any other user to specifically right click the exe and select 'run as administrator' I have a local admin that I would like to use in a script to automate that action and applies the creds for the user.

I have tried the following.

```
# Construct the credentials object
$username = "svr-rds\xxx"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxx" -AsPlainText -Force    
$cred = New-Object PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password

Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $cred -WindowStyle Hidden `
 '-noprofile -command "Start-Process C:\Montana\Montana.exe /k -Verb RunAs"'
```

I have found though that the runas command no matter how you use it opens the application as an empty application frame, if I've researched right, the runas command is not the same as specifically elevating to admin.

is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Note you stated...

> epos application that runs fine under the user that initially
>   installed it...

Then to install and app, you need to be Admin on the box or use Admin creds when prompted. So, the app is installed as an Admin and global to all users and that app is associated with the user initial user identity only. So,  when another user logs on to this what appears to be a shared workstation, that app is never associated with any other user profile. So, one must use the installer identity.

PoSH notwithstanding. RunAs has never meant 'Run Elevated'. It's always meant run with the supplied identity.

Suggestion:

Why not just create a shortcut to the .exe and set it's properties to run as admin?
You can just use that to launch the app with the shortcut settings.

```
invoke-item 'AppName.lnk'
```

Example, I run an a regular use all the time, my PoSH host environment is set to restricted. Yet, because I do all things admin in PoSH, I start PoSH as admin and elevated this way:

```
# Shortcut properties for the ISE
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:contoso\Administrator "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted PowerShell_ISE.exe"

# Shortcut properties for the Console Host
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:contoso\Administrator "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"
```

Or just create a shortcut and set the 'Run as administrator'  checkbox under the advanced tab of the shortcut properties. if you don't need the extra ExecutionPolicy step as above. Then the whole invoke step.